# Explaining regression performance differences

Tags: regression, cross-validation, ridge-regression

**Context**

I have a regression framework and two sets of data. Using leave-one-out cross-validation, the first set gives very good performance and the second set gives rather poor performance. I need to explain the reason for this difference in performance.

Having looked at the data, it is clear that the first set is a much easier test case. The data in the first set does not vary as much as in the second set. In addition, the test and training data of the first set are strikingly similar, which is not the case in the second dataset.

To explain the reason for the performance difference, I can show these differences in data qualitatively using pictures of the physical phenomena being modeled. However, I would also like to quantify these dataset differences and relate it to the performance discrepancy.

**Questions**

What metrics can I use to show that the first dataset is a trivial test case and that the second set is more challenging?

As a statistician, what else would you want to know in order to be confident that the performance discrepancy was caused by these differences in data and not something else?

Comment: @Josh You added the tag `ridge-regression`. Does it mean that you have a large number of predictors and/or that you suspect that it has something to do with the observed difference in prediction accuracy?

Comment: @chl I added the tag since it is the regression method that is used by the framework.

Comment: @Josh: the answer may depend upon the measure for which you are optimizing: do you optimize for AUC, for missclassification,... Can you specify? This may also answer my other question: what does 'rather poor performance' mean? Finally: have you tried with something like tenfold CV?

Comment: @Nick I am using ridge regression to estimate a vector of angles; the first dataset gives a mean error of around 5-8 degrees, whereas the second set gives a mean error of 14-40 degrees (hence the 'poor performance'). No, I am unable to use tenfold CV due to limited data: the data relates to 1 of 4 subjects, each test set contains the data of 1 subject and the remaining 3 make up the training set. I need the test subject to be completely unseen in the training set.

Comment: @Josh: I hope I'm misunderstanding here: does the above mean you have only 4 observations? Since you're using ridge regression, I assume you are doing some variable selection of sorts. I believe variable selection and 4 observations do not match...

Comment: @Nick No, I have 4 subjects that were observed over time. Each time instant is an observation, which gives about 400 observations per subject.

Comment: @Josh: so how does this prevent you from doing ten-fold crossvalidation?

Comment: @Nick Because I am trying to determine how well the framework can generalise to an unseen subject. Given only 4 subjects, how can I perform tenfold CV without including the test subject within the training set?

Comment: This may be oversimplifying for your situation, but: say you have 100 obs per subject. Throw the 3 x 100 training observations together (perhaps add a variable indicating subject for repeated measurement). The result is a training dataset w 300 obs. Then use this (w 10-fold CV) to fit a model, and evaluate on your test data.